# ehcache cache invalidation and use of multicasting

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have 80 caches and 41 servers and we use manual discovery.

When caches invalidate in one server there will be 3200 connections and at least same amount of requests, invoking invalidation for all other servers.

My question is that if we I decide to use multicast how many connections will be established on application level?

How exactly does ehcache use multicast? Ehcache docs tells that ehcache uses multicast for peer discovery, from which I understand for cache invalidation multicast means nothing. Is that true?

Please do not post ehcache documentation links in response.